# Imagick PHP Issue - Massive Quality loss of .png or .jpeg after "mergeImageLayers" operation

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

I'm currently facing an issue regarding the image quality after a "mergeImageLayers" operation with ImageMagick. I merge three seperate .png pictures each one of them has initially arround 22KB and looks fine. After the "merging-prozess" I get an 5KB picture in bad quality either as .png or .jpeg.

How can I built in a compression method to ensure higher quality? At the moment the images are sadly barely useable. Here is the function I built (it also does color-replacement):

```
    function mergeImages($BASE,$MASK,$TEXT,$TARGET,$FILL,$FUZZ){

    $layerMethodType = \Imagick::LAYERMETHOD_COMPARECLEAR;
    $img1 = new Imagick(realpath($BASE));

    $img1->floodFillPaintImage($FILL, $FUZZ* \Imagick::getQuantum(),$TARGET,0,0, true);
    $fuzz = $FUZZ* $img1->getQuantumRange()['quantumRangeLong'];
    $img1->opaquePaintImage($TARGET, $FILL, $fuzz, false, Imagick::CHANNEL_DEFAULT);

    $img2 = new Imagick(realpath($MASK));
    $img1->addImage($img2);
    $img1->setImageFormat('png');

    $img3 = new Imagick(realpath($TEXT));
    $img3->floodFillPaintImage($FILL, $FUZZ* \Imagick::getQuantum(),$TARGET,0,0, true);
    $fuzz = $FUZZ* $img1->getQuantumRange()['quantumRangeLong'];
    $img3->opaquePaintImage($TARGET, $FILL, $fuzz, false, Imagick::CHANNEL_DEFAULT);
    $img1->addImage($img3);
    $img1->setImageFormat('jpeg');
    $result = $img1->mergeImageLayers($layerMethodType);

    header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
    $result->getImageBlob();
    return $result;
}
```

Hopefully one can help me out with this. I allready tried the following:

```
$img1->setImageFormat('jpeg');
$img1->setImageCompression(\Imagick::COMPRESSION_NO );
```

and

```
$img->setCompression(Imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG); 
$img->setCompressionQuality(90);
```

as .jpeg or .png in all cases the new images has 5KB

Thx in advanced for your help!

#### Update

I have tried different images and the KB went up imideately. Simple pictures like Icons a playicon for instatance simple look not good. Fotos on the other side are quite well compressed and have a good quality. But the "compression-problem" still remains -> the above mentioned solutions simple don't work. Now I have to do the "compress_image()" workarround.

Comment: You are not using Imagemagick directly but the php API and so I have modified the title and tags. I would try something simple first with fixed images and see what happens.

Comment: thx for changing and reviewing. I will try different operations!